# What is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^n a^k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was trying to find out a general solution for $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}k^na^k$$ where a, n are some constants. But I was not able to figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2):

The easy thing to do is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k}{j} a^k = \frac{a^j}{(1-a)^{j+1}}
\tag1
$$
Next note that, for fixed $n$, the sequence $k^n$ is a linear combination of the sequences $\binom{k}{0},\binom{k}{1},\binom{k}{2},\dots,\binom{k}{n}$.  The coefficients are [Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) times factorials.  So, the OP may be done as a linear combination of the formula $(1)$.

Example (see note below)
$$
k^4 = 24\binom{k}{4}+36\binom{k}{3}+14\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}
$$
and therefore
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^4 a^k = 
24\;\frac{a^4}{(1-a)^5}+36\;\frac{a^3}{(1-a)^4}+14\;\frac{a^2}{(1-a)^3} + \frac{a}{(1-a)^2}
\\ =
\frac{a^4+11a^3+11a^2+a}{(1-a)^5}
$$

---

Note.
Row $4$ of the Stirling numbers of the second kind
$$
0\quad 1\quad 7\quad 6\quad 1
$$
times factorials
$$
1\quad 1\quad 2\quad 6\quad 24
$$
gives us our coefficients
$$
0\quad 1\quad 14\quad 36\quad 24
$$

Comment: Thank you very much I got it

Answer (score 1):

There is no "solution".

You probably meant a closed form. It does not really exist in terms of elementary functions. Yet if you have a basic knowledge in Special Function, this is nothing but the definition of the so called *Polylogarithm* that is:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} k^n\ a^k = PolyLog[-n, a]$$

More about that special function, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm and here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html

Comment: Other notation for the polylog $\mathrm{Li}_{-n}(a)$.