# The series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^kp^n$

Tags: power-series, p-adic-number-theory

Let $k$ be a non-negative integer, $p$ be a prime number and consider the $\mathbb{Q}_p$-series $a(k,p) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^kp^n$ (it converges, since $n^kp^n \to 0$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for obvious reasons). Prove that $a(k,p) \in \mathbb{Q}$ and that for any fixed $k$ the set $\{a(k,p): p - \mbox{prime}\}$ is infinite.

I am not aware of a general criterion to verify whether a series in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$. Wolfram Alpha gave a really implicit closed form of this series; on the other hand I see that using derivatives suitably could work, but did not reach anything proper.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you do $k=0$?  Can you do $k=1$?  To what extent does this work: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3525783/442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sketch:** You can compute $a(k,p)$ directly using the geometric series and its derivations:

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
so that $a(0,p)=f(p)=\frac{1}{1-p}$ is rational.

Now $f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n}$, which means $a(1,p)=pf'(p)$ is also rational and so on.

In general, for the function $a(k,x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^k x^n$, we have 
$$\frac{d}{dx} a(k,x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^{k+1} x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^{k+1} x^{n}=\frac{a(k+1,x)}{x}$$

**Edit:** Well $a(0,p)=\{\frac{1}{1-p}:p\text{ is prime}\}$ is an infinite set. Now $a(1,p)=p\frac{d}{dp}(0,p)=\frac{p}{(1-p)^2}$ thus $\{a(1,p):p\text{ is prime}\}$ is also infinite.

Now suppose the set $\{a(k,p):p\text{ is prime}\}$ is infinite and prove by induction that $\{a(k+1,p):p\text{ is prime}\}$ is also infinite.

Comment: Great! What about the second part (that with $k$ fixed and $p$ varying we get infinitely many distinct numbers)?

Comment: You may note that for example the set $\{a(0,p)\}=\{\frac{1}{1-p}:p\text{ is prime}\}$

Comment: and note that $a(k,p)$ is related to $a(k-1,p)$

Comment: could you help me again for the second part please? So I see your point for $a(0,p)$ but I am not even really sure whether $a(k,p_1) = a(k,p_2)$ implies $p_1 = p_2$ (since $p_1\frac{d}{dp_1}a(k-1,p_1) = p_2\frac{d}{dp_2}a(k-1,p_2) $ is already quite complicated to study. What do you think?

Comment: I add something to the answer