# Calculating the summation $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^3}{3^n}$

Tags: summation

Evaluate $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^3}{3^n}.$$

I started my using casework, listing out some terms when plugging values in. $0, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{8}{9}, 1.$ I noticed that there is no common ratio involved in these terms. I'm not sure if I can do any partial fraction decomposition here either. I'm not sure if it telescopes.

Comment: [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%5E3%2F3%5En%2C+n%3D0+to+infinity) there is partial sum: perhaps to prove it you can use induction, but I think that it is difficult since the partial sum has transcendental form.

Comment: Thanks, I think these helps after reading both of them.

Comment: Anyway I repeat that the induction is too much complicate: the partial sum has a trascendental form!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I was writing up an answer that does the summation without calculus. It is doable by writing as a multi sum and then switching the order of summation.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Okay, so we are waiting for your answer.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro lol! The post is closed, it will not accept answers anymore, hence why I wrote a comment.

Comment: How come it is closed?

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3525783/442